# r - counting hours of intervals by year or day of week

Tags: r, tidyverse, intervals, lubridate, hour

Imagine a table with the date and hour of work for some police officers. We have the initial date-time and the final date-time for each shift. I want to count the hours per year, for exemple. I can do that, but it's quite a complex task because of the shifts with with hours in 2 different years. Is there a quick way to do that? This seens to be a pretty common task, but i couldn't find any package to do that.
For example, if i want to count the hours worked by day of the week, I have the same problem. Any indications?

Data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tabela <- tibble(
  data_hora_chegada = c(
    ymd_hms("2018-07-05 18:00:00"),
    ymd_hms("2019-05-05 20:00:00"),
    ymd_hms("2019-12-31 23:00:00")
  ),
  data_hora_saida = c(
    ymd_hms("2018-07-06 16:00:00"),
    ymd_hms("2019-05-05 22:30:00"),
    ymd_hms("2020-01-01 15:00:00")
  )
)

tabela %>%
  mutate(
    intervalo = lubridate::interval(
      data_hora_chegada,
      data_hora_saida
    )
  ) -> tabela
```

Expected Output:

```
Year|Hours
2018| 22
2019| 3,5
2020| 15

# or similarly, with "Day of Week" instead of "Year"
```

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: @akrun i added the expected output! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate correctly considering the turn of year, you'd basically need to split your record in two, then you can perform the calculation of *intervalo* taking advantage of the code you have already written, and then do the summarizing.

```
tabela.split <-
  tabela %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(
    {
      my_row <- .

      new_df <- data.frame(
        Year = year(my_row$data_hora_chegada) : year(my_row$data_hora_saida)
      ) %>%
        mutate(
          data_hora_chegada = ISOdate(Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
          data_hora_saida = ISOdate(Year+1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        )

      new_df[1, "data_hora_chegada"] <- my_row$data_hora_chegada
      new_df[nrow(new_df), "data_hora_saida"] <- my_row$data_hora_saida

      new_df
    }
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

print(tabela.split)
```

This is code is ready for any interval so if there are more than two years in the interval, it will generate as many records as needed for all the years in the interval span.

Output

```
   Year data_hora_chegada   data_hora_saida    
* <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1  2018 2018-07-05 18:00:00 2018-07-06 16:00:00
2  2019 2019-05-05 20:00:00 2019-05-05 22:30:00
3  2019 2019-12-31 23:00:00 2020-01-01 00:00:00
4  2020 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01 15:00:00
```

Now you can use `group_by()` and `summarize()` to get totals by year.

```
tabela.split %>%
  mutate(
    intervalo = as.numeric(lubridate::interval(
      data_hora_chegada,
      data_hora_saida
    ))
  ) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(Hours = round(sum(intervalo)/3600,1))
```

Output

```
   Year Hours
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2018  22  
2  2019   3.5
3  2020  15
```

However to make it break by any time measure as dynamically specified would be a much complex task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. You can look at intersections between each calendar year and the intervals you identified in `tabela`.

```
# Create a vector of years, from minimum to maximum
all_years <- with(tabela, seq(min(year(data_hora_chegada)), max(year(data_hora_saida))))

# Create list of year intervals for these years
year_intervals <- lapply(all_years, function(x) interval(ymd_hms(paste0(x, "-01-01 00:00:00")), ymd_hms(paste0(x+1, "-01-01 00:00:00"))))
names(year_intervals) <- all_years

# Determine overlap/intersection between single year intervals and tabela intervals
year_overlaps <- lapply(year_intervals, intersect, tabela$intervalo)

# Convert to data frame and sum hours for each year
data.frame(Hours = rowSums(t(sapply(year_overlaps, c)), na.rm = TRUE)/3600)
```

**Output**

```
     Hours
2018  22.0
2019   3.5
2020  15.0
```